# SVG with inner image won't show up when uploaded to server

Tags: html, svg

I have the following piece of code, it works in w3schools.com but won't work when running with a local server ... what am I missing ?

```
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="50%" height="50%">

      <defs>
      <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="http://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/grass/natural-green-trimmed-grass-sport-field-background-header.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
      </pattern>
      </defs>

      <path fill="url(#img1)" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"
      d="M 50,50 90,90 130,50 110,10 70,10 Z" />

    </svg>
```

I also tried to use a local image which is located on my server

Comment: You're missing the XLink namespace on the `<svg>` element: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="50%" height="50%">`

Comment: It still won't show up anything else I might have missed ? thanks for the quick response though

Comment: If you replace the fill with fill="blue" does it work then?

Comment: Works like a charm for me: https://jsfiddle.net/r776fpcd/. With `local server`, do you mean `http://localhost` or `file:///`?

Comment: using localserver, and blue works. I think I know why it is happening though, I removed everything on my page except the SVG and it worked ... there might be a CSS or something that overrides it . thanks for your help :)

Comment: <base href=""> was interrupting it